# Understanding ASP.net mvc4 code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

   }
```

What does this code do? Index and login are views here?

Comment: Index is action and login is controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tells MVC to redirect to specified action instead of rendering HTML. In this case, browser receives the redirect notification and make a new request for the specified action. This acts like as Response.Redirect() in Asp.Net WebForm.
Moreover, RedirectToAction construct a redirect url to a specific action/controller in your application and use the route table to generate the correct URL.

For more about this look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx